# Best way to handle HttpClient Response

Tags: java, string, memory-management, apache-commons-httpclient

I have the following method in my HTTP Servlet. Basically its a simple Java servlet that acts as a proxy. Browsers make the request for the XML data to the servlet, the servlet opens a connection to get the XML data, and prints the response. According to the [docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) on Apache HttpClient the method `method.getResponseBodyAsString(20000)` is discouraged.

> Unless used carefully they can easily lead to out of memory conditions, since they imply buffering of the complete entity in memory.

So I'm trying to do this the encouraged way, but I'm not sure whether [this solution](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/) is actually better. **My question** is whether the handling of the response shown below also implies buffering of the complete entity since after the while loop the StringBuilder, xmlResponse, has the entire entity in memory anyway? The response is paginated and likely less than 10,000 characters.

```
private void submitHTTPQuery(String searchStr)  {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  GetMethod method = new GetMethod(searchStr);
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
  int statusCode = 0;
  try {
    client.getHostConfiguration();
    statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

//Discouraged methods
// byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
// String responseString = method.getResponseBodyAsString(20000);

    reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
      method.getResponseBodyAsStream(), method.getResponseCharSet()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
    } 
    xmlResponse = result;

    }
} catch (HttpException e) {
    logger.error("Search Servlet HTTP Error",e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Search Servlet IO Error",e);
} finally {
    method.releaseConnection();

    try {
        if(reader !=null ){
            reader.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("failed to close GSA Search Reader", e);
    }

}
```

}

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html
https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Comment: You're linking documentation to the httpclient 3 but your question is tagged httpclient 4.

Comment: There are a few different approaches here. If you're really just proxying a request, just use a proxy. You are also reading the entire response into memory which - so assuming you know that is ok, there is no reason for you to be 'strongly discouraged'  from using the convenience methods. Use away, it's going to be more efficient than your somewhat questionable 'stream and concatenate line by line' implementation